# Java JSSE RMI SSL file gets access denied

Tags: java, ssl, rmi, jsse

For university security lab work I have to create a simple client/server application using RMI. For secure communication between client and server I wanted to use SSL. [Oracle has example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/samples/index.html) so I tried to use it. And I get errors. I try to start server rmi.HelloImpl.java which uses rmi.RMISSLServerSocketFactory.java where the file mentioned in error is defined. And I am getting this **error**:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.5\lib\idea_rt.jar=54269:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.5\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Agne\IdeaProjects\jssesamples\out\production\jssesamples" rmi.HelloImpl
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "testkeys" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:127)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at rmi.RMISSLServerSocketFactory.<init>(RMISSLServerSocketFactory.java:27)
    at rmi.HelloImpl.main(HelloImpl.java:34)
HelloImpl err: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "testkeys" "read")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "testkeys" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
```

I checked my Java is 8 version, I use IntelliJ IDEA, I run it as administrator. Same error I got, when I tried to create the file in this code too, before it goes to testkeys. Then almost indentical error with new file name and access is denied in write. What am I missing?

And code in these two classes which are the main participations:

**HelloImpl**

```
package rmi;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class HelloImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Hello {

    private static final int PORT = 2019;

    public HelloImpl() throws Exception {
        super(PORT,
              new RMISSLClientSocketFactory(),
              new RMISSLServerSocketFactory());
    }

    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // Create and install a security manager
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        }

        try {
            // Create SSL-based registry
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(PORT,
                new RMISSLClientSocketFactory(),
                new RMISSLServerSocketFactory());

            HelloImpl obj = new HelloImpl();

            // Bind this object instance to the name "HelloServer"
            registry.bind("HelloServer", obj);

            System.out.println("HelloServer bound in registry");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("HelloImpl err: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**RMISSLServerSocketFactory**

```
    package rmi;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class RMISSLServerSocketFactory implements RMIServerSocketFactory {

    /*
     * Create one SSLServerSocketFactory, so we can reuse sessions
     * created by previous sessions of this SSLContext.
     */
    private SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = null;

    public RMISSLServerSocketFactory() throws Exception {
        try {
            // set up key manager to do server authentication
            SSLContext ctx;
            KeyManagerFactory kmf;
            KeyStore ks;

            char[] passphrase = "passphrase".toCharArray();
            ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(new FileInputStream("testkeys"), passphrase);

            kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kmf.init(ks, passphrase);

            ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

            ssf = ctx.getServerSocketFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public ServerSocket createServerSocket(int port) throws IOException {
            return ssf.createServerSocket(port);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        } else if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the security manager. You only need it if you're using the codebase feature, and you aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you install an RMISecurityManager, you need to have a policy file that specifies the permissions that your application will need in a security policy file.  I think there used to be a policytool application that would help you write that file, and the error message tells you what permission you need to add to the file.  In your case, it looks like something like:

```
grant {
    filePermission "testKeys", "read" 
}
```

would need to be part of your security policy.

Comment: For me it works with: 
`grant { permission java.security.AllPermission; };`
But I like your solution better for security reasons 
`grant { permission java.io.FilePermission "testkeys", "read"; };`. 
Only problem, that I get access denied 
`Launcher failed - "Dump Threads" and "Exit" actions are unavailable (access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.5\bin\breakgen64.dll" "read"))
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:2019" "listen,resolve")`

Comment: You would need to add those permissions to the file, too ... That's the problem/feature with not using "AllPermission" - you get to find out what all the things are that the code needs permission to do, then add them all to the policy file.  IIRC, mine ended up with something like 15-20 permission lines in it...

Comment: @moilejter And the problem with using ’AllPermission` is that you may as well get rid of the security manager altogether.